# How do you order JSON data - order returned results from lowest to highest

Tags: python, json

```
for val in online_json["payload"]["orders"]:
    if val["user"]["status"] == "ingame" and val["order_type"] == "sell":
        username = str(val["user"]["ingame_name"])
        quantity = int(val["quantity"])
        game_price = int(val["gameprice"])

        print(username + ' is selling ' + str(quantity) + ' for ' + str(game_price) + '  each.')
```

Currently the result of the query is in whatever order the API returns which leads to a lot of clutter,
I would like to order the results from the lowest **game_price** to highest to easily display the lowest price alongside the rest of the information.

Comment: Give some data in your code.

Comment: Please provide sample JSON structure

Comment: You don't have any JSON here; you only have a `dict` that might have resulted from decoding a JSON object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `sorted` and appropriate `key` which'll be `lambda x:int(x['gameprice'])`. Also you can simplify your `print` instead of using concatenation, use multiple params

```
for val in sorted(online_json["payload"]["orders"], key=lambda x:int(x['gameprice'])):
    if val["user"]["status"] == "ingame" and val["order_type"] == "sell":
        username = str(val["user"]["ingame_name"])
        quantity = int(val["quantity"])
        game_price = int(val["gameprice"])

        print(username, 'is selling', quantity, 'for', game_price, 'each.')
```